# launch a shortcode from a link

Tags: shortcode

Am in wordpress. I have a shortcode `[gallery link="none" size="full" ids="18,17,15,14"]`

I want it to run when I click a link. I did try using `do_shortcode` but as yet I can't figure out how to approach this.

Currently user clicks an image which goes to another page which has the above shortcode in it - so the wp gallery opens up. This is all fine except when the user closes the gallery they are left looking at the page which has the shortcode in it - which I don't want them to see - this is the real issue.

I thought if I could in some run the shortcode straight when the user presses the link then when they close the gallery they'd be back on the right page.

Comment: What do you mean "run when you click a link"? Can you explain more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: are you using a plugin for the gallery or just the wordpress built in?

Comment: Wordpress  built in one with the ''gallery carousel without jetpack'